# Mamp wordpress transfer

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

Hi i've been building a website on wordpress offline using mamp on my macbook laptop. My laptop was old and very slow. I bought a new laptop and want to move what i have done already from my old laptop to my new one. Can someone point me in the right direction to a tutorial for this or describe the best way? Many thanks. Greg

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will need to download the databases from your old laptop.
if you open mamp, turn on the webservers and then go to the mamp homepage (or go to localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser).
Then click on the export tab, download everything (you might want to choose the option to put it inside of a zip folder).
Now copy that zip folder over to the new mac, go to the same web address (if mamp is installed and running except this time you want to import.
Choose the zip file,
put all of your wordpress files inside of the mamp web directory and try to access your site.

Comment: Also if your new laptop is not a mac then i woudl suggest you download wamp (pretty much the windows alterative) you will then be able to access phpmyadmin  and the web directory is C:/wamp/www

Answer (score 0):

First you have to export the contents of your WordPress database. You can do this by running localhost/phpMyAdmin in your browser.

1. Once you are in phpMyAdmin select your WordPress database. You can find the name of your WordPress database in your wp-config.php file in your main WordPress folder. It looks like this:

   define('DB_NAME', 'wpdb');

   This will display all tables in the database on the right hand side of the screen.
2. Click on the Check All checkbox found at the bottom of the list of tables.
3. Click on the Export tab.
4. Click on the Custom Export method. This will display additional options.
5. Click on the Save Output to a File radio button. If you do not do this the result of the export operation will be displayed on the screen.
6. [Optional] In the Object Creation Options you may select the Add Create Database option. Alternatively, you can create the database first in your new laptop.
7. Click on the Go button found at the bottom of the page. This will cause the creation of a file with a name of .sql. You need to copy this file into your new laptop.

After exporting the contents of the database, you may choose to copy your entire WordPress folder to the new machine. You can do this by compressing the entire WordPress folder into a zip file and copying it into your new machine.

In your new laptop...

1. Install mamp and start Apache and MySQL.
2. Unzip the contents of the zip file into the htdocs folder.
3. Type localhost/phpmyadmin on your browser's address bar.
4. If you did not select the Add Create Database option when you exported your WordPress database, you need to create the database first.
5. To create the database, click on the database tab in phpMyAdmin.
6. Enter the database name in the space provided. Make sure that you use the same database name as in your previous installation (get the name from wp-config.php file) and click on the Create button.
7. Once you have created the database select it from the tree view on the left hand side of the page.
8. There will be no tables displayed on the right hand side.
9. Click on the import tab.
10. Click the Choose File button. This will cause the Finder app to display. Select the file that you created when you exported the contents of the WordPress database.
11. After selecting the file click on the Go button. This will let phpMyAdmin create and populate the different WordPress tables.

Type localhost/ to see if everything installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I made these two tutorials for this exact thing:

Part 1:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn-8OvwFdBY

Part 2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIIJBdpRzjM

Hopefully they help. :)